# Classes in python need guidance

Tags: python

In the second last line of the following code : `studySpell(Confundo()`
In which function `studySpell` makes a new instance of the `Confundo` class by assigning it to `spell`. My question is that after the execution of the second to last line, why does `spell.incantation` return `'Accio'`? Shouldn't it return `'Confundo'`?

```
class Spell(object):
    def __init__(self, incantation, name):
        self.name = name
        self.incantation = incantation

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.incantation + '\n' + self.getDescription()

    def getDescription(self):
        return 'No description'

    def execute(self):
        print(self.incantation)


class Accio(Spell):
    def __init__(self):
        Spell.__init__(self, 'Accio', 'Summoning Charm')

class Confundo(Spell):
    def __init__(self):
        Spell.__init__(self, 'Confundo', 'Confundus Charm')

    def getDescription(self):
        return 'Causes the victim to become confused and befuddled.'

def studySpell(spell):
    print(spell)

>>> spell = Accio()
>>> spell.execute()
Accio
>>> studySpell(spell)
Summoning Charm Accio
No description
>>> studySpell(Confundo())
Confundus Charm Confundo
Causes the victim to become confused and befuddled.
>>> print(spell.incantation)
Accio
```

if you don't understand my point let me know I will try to preach more.

Comment: Why do you believe the call to `studySpell()` would change the `spell` instance? `spell` is still an instance of `Accio`.

Comment: While it doesn't make any difference here, you would normally use `super()` to call base class ctors (it will make a difference if you have diamond inheritance patterns).

Answer (score 0):

The `studySpell` function doesn't "assign" to the `spell` variable (the global one). It creates a new, local, variable (also named `spell`) that shadows the global `spell` variable and goes away after the function is done executing.

Comment: #thebjorn ohh i get it know, thank you very much. I couldn't saw that coming.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you have to reassign the variable, and then execute the method:

```
spell = Accio()
spell.execute()
studySpell(spell)
studySpell(Confundo())
spell = Confundo()
print(spell.incantation)
```

---

```
Accio
Summoning Charm Accio
No description
Confundus Charm Confundo
Causes the victim to become confused and befuddled.
Confundo
```

Your code, as you posted, is working as should be.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Spell:
  
  def __init__(self, incantation, name):
    self.name = name
    self.incantation = incantation

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name + ' ' + self.incantation + '\n' + 
    self.get_description()

  def get_description(self):
    return 'No description'

  def execute(self):
    print(self.incantation)

class Accio(Spell):

  def __init__(self):
    Spell.__init__(self, 'Accio', 'Summoning Charm')

class Confundo(Spell):

  def __init__(self):
    Spell.__init__(self, 'Confundo', 'Confundus Charm')

  def get_description(self):
    return 'Causes the victim to become confused and befuddled.'

  def study_spell(spell):
    print(spell)

spell = Accio()
spell.execute()
study_spell(spell)
study_spell(Confundo())
print(spell.incantation)
```

Comment: Hi Koppu, welcome to SO, maybe your answer is correct and it can help to resolve the question, but it's necessary you write a description of your code. Please check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer